# Controlling Razor views programmatically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, content-management-system, viewengine

Is is possible to programmatically control Razor views? Can I reach the different `RenderSection` parts or change the `Layout` definition in code?

I'm looking into possibilities to use Razor syntax in the presentation layer of a CMS application. Might Spark be a better choice because of it's (parseable) XML syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://razorengine.codeplex.com and http://tqcblog.com/2011/01/23/precompiled-razor-for-shared-views-and-mono/ - you can convert razor views to c# code and set the views to use a custom base class that has whatever additional functionality you need.

You may also be able do something with the viewstart file - although set up as a razor view, it is effectively custom code that modifies the settings of all views, including the layout.