# Passing Razor Markup to view and process it

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I've searched the internet for days now with no luck finding this.

My model has a property which holds a chunk of html containing Razor markup.
exmaple:

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public string Content = "<div>@Html.TextBox(\"UserName\")</div>";
}
```

In the view, I display that with

```
@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(Model.Content).toString())
```

I need to be able to convert the Razor markup into html, although because the Content is dropped in through the model, the view engine doesn't process it.

- I have tried simply dropping in the Content, using just .Raw(Model.Content), .Encode(Model.Content), nothing works.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems like you are going against the whole purpose of the MVC framework. Why not just pass the actual data from your Model and create the markup using that data in the View?

Comment: Good point, and to elaborate on the project: The site uses a page editor, which will store the entire contents of a partial view in a database and have it loaded when requested. So, I need to be able to read a string from the database which contains the razor markup.

Comment: I suspect you will have to decode the razor into HTML before saving it to your DB.

Comment: Possibly answered here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153090/controlling-razor-views-programmatically

Comment: "The site uses a page editor, which will store the entire contents of a partial view in a database and have it loaded when requested." agreed. But uou should only store the value in the database and have the markup present in the partial view and then you can pass these values using model.

Comment: This is against the MVC framework, I doubt if this is even possible.

Comment: I wouldn't say its against the MVC framework, they never declared "Thou shalt not decode Razor manually", lmao. 

If the RazorViewEngine can decode the markup, there must surely exist a way to manually do it in the controller. Still looking into it, i'll post back if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) package which allows you to parse and execute Razor code. This being said I would not recommend you giving your users the power of editing directly Razor templates. You are opening a huge security hole in your website.

There are other templating engines such as [DotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/) for example which are better suited for scenarios where you don't trust user input.